# Subset based on text & date columns

Tags: r, regex, subset

I have a dataset which includes a text field and a date field. Sample in .csv format below:

```
ID,Text,Date,BP,Person
1,This is Text!,6/24/2013,120,Bob
2,I don't like Text.,6/24/2013,114,Bob
3,Text files are stupid.,6/24/2013,310,Genny
4,"The Cezanne, for 500 please.",6/24/2013,45,Glenn
5,I enhanced my coffee with Kahlua,6/25/2013,105,Genny
6,And something else here.,6/24/2013,200,Bob
```

I want to remove any record where the Text field does not contain the word "[Tt]ext" & is dated 6/24/2013. So, records 4 & 6 would be dropped while everything else remains.

I've tried subsetting the frame like so:

```
newframe <- frame[!which(grep('[Tt]ext', frame$Text) &
                         frame$Date == '6/24/2013'), ]
```

But that got me nowhere.

Comment: does `grepl` do what you need? it returns a logical vector instead of `grep` which returns an index of positions which meet your conditions.  This would match it with the logicals returned by your date condition.

Comment: Yeah, that logical vector was what I needed. Need to study up on my regular expression commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my final code looks like, using the `grepl` command:

`newframe <- frame[ !(!grepl('[Tt]ext', frame$Plain.Text) & frame$Date == '6/24/2013', ]`

This gets me the original dataframe, excluding records that don't contain "[Tt]ext" on 6/24/2013.

Answer (score 2):

Please you should give your data in a redable structure. Using `grepl` , this should work:

```
frame[with(frame,
   !grepl('[Tt]ext', Text) & Date == '6/24/2013'),]
  ID                         Text      Date  BP Person
4  4 The Cezanne, for 500 please. 6/24/2013  45  Glenn
6  6     And something else here. 6/24/2013 200    Bob
```